# Grab a menu from a page on a different domain

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to grab a menu from a page on a different domain.  The reason I  have 4 domains with the same menu and it's db driven. I would rather update the menu in one place instead of 4 places.

For example: domain2.com uses the code below to grab the contents from domain1.com.  This works but I'm displaying everything on the blog page.  I want to display only the horizontal menu.  Is this possible?  What code can I add below to display the horizontal menu only?  Or is there a better way  to do this for all domains?

```
   <?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mydomain/blog");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 3);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    echo $result
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regular expressions (e.g. with [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match)) to match some html from your page. But I really recommend to use a better solution, maybe one of those:

- Implement a clean API to retrieve your menu data and then build the menu on your sites manually instead of grabbing the rendered one
- Cache your menu since its expensive to make a http request every time
- Access the database that stores you menu directly (also you should cache the data in this case)

Comment: regex should not be used for html parsing. You should recommend using a DOMParser and XPath

Comment: I can't implement a API out of the blue.  Many pages already built too much of a mess.   I can't access the db.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on how I can add something to my code to get this to work?  All I need is the header and the footer.